# How to display the "left hand" radical as Unicode text?

Tags: radicals, fonts

I want to display the two parts of the 右 character in a document. The first part, 口, is easy. The problem lies in the second part, which some sources call "left hand" radical.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ0ZhZDCRWk) calls it a character derived from the 十 (ten) radical. However, the drawing in the video is different from the one found in [zhongwen.com](http://zhongwen.com/cgi-bin/zipux.cgi?=%A5k), which is more similar to the original drawing (but at zhongwen.com it's an image, and I want an Unicode character).

Actually I've (probably) found the character I want (?) from [here](http://www.hanzicraft.com/character/%E5%B7%A6). But, even after I installed some 10 different Chinese fonts in my Debian system, it still displays as a square with numbers on it, and sometimes as a large blank space. I've updated the font cache, and still nothing. So, do I need some very specific font or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CJK IDS](https://github.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-ids) has this entry for 右:

```
U+53F3   右   ⿸口
U+20087
```

Which seems to match what you found.

You do need a font that includes CJK Extension B for 20087. No problem on my Mac, it seems to have lots of them with this character.

Comment: Where are the entries for CJK IDS? And how could I know that `U+20087` is in CJK Extension B?

Comment: @Rodrigo CJK IDS is here: https://github.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-ids  It is more of a visual structural breakdown of characters than a linguistic breakdown, but sometimes there are correspondences.

Comment: @Rodrigo Another easy place to find the composition is a google search which will bring up https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/右

Comment: @Rodrigo A google search for U+20087 will quickly give you info about what part of unicode it is in, e.g. https://codepoints.net/U+20087?lang=en

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, I've found it in a few sites, but wasn't sure because the proper font wasn't installed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, the top left part of「右」and the top left part of「左」have different origins. Also, neither of them have anything to do with「十」.

---

The top left part of「右」as a stand-alone character is now written as「又」. It was originally a picture of a *right hand*.

## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.5.15
[合集24506](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=24506&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)36</kbd>
　<kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

- The「口」in「右」was added later to distinguish between the meaning *right hand (anatomy)* and *right side*.

  ## <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  夨令方彝
  [集成9901](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9901&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  [睡・封](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)21</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

The top left part of「左」, unsurprisingly, was originally a picture of a *left hand*. As a stand-alone character, it is now written as「」.

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]
[粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)950
[合集28882](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28882&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
三年師兌簋
[集成4318](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4318&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

- The「工」(*picture of a tool*) in「左」was added later to bring out the meaning of *assistance, help*, now written as「佐」.

  ## <kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  虢季子白盤
  [集成10173](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10173&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image]
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

---

The top left component of「右」and「左」look very similar in the modern script, but the original components meant different things and had different pronunciations. For example,「又」, being the top left component of「右」, is also found at the top left part of both of the following characters, where it contributes both meaning and sound:

- 「有」(**yǒu**; *picture of a hand*「又」**yòu** *holding a piece of meat*「⺼・肉」*> to have [something]*)
- 「友」(**yǒu**; *picture of two right hands*「又」**yòu** *> friend*)

---

**References:**

- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)